# Is there a way to analyse & compare djvu files?

Tags: djvu

I have two .djvu files, seemingly identical except for their different size.

How can I find out where the size difference is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Just open it with [DjVuLibre](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djvu/files/DjVuLibre_Windows/3.5.25%2B4.9/) and you'll the res in the bottom right corner.